# Saving in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am following a tutorials in gontuseries. So I have this code that persist two records in the database.

My Test class:

```
public class Test {

    private HibernateUtility util;
    private Session session;
    private Transaction tx;

    public Test() {
        util = HibernateUtility.getInstance();
        session = util.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
    }

    public void simpleSaving() {

        List<StudentInfo> students = new ArrayList<StudentInfo>();

        StudentInfo student = new StudentInfo();
        student.setRollNo(1);
        student.setName("Jo");
        student.setBirthdate(new Date());

        StudentInfo student2 = new StudentInfo();
        student.setRollNo(2);
        student.setName("JC");
        student.setBirthdate(new Date());

        students.add(student);
        students.add(student2);

        for(StudentInfo s : students) {
            session.save(s);
        }

        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        util.getSessionFactory().close();

    }
}
```

And this is my POJO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student_info")
public class StudentInfo implements Serializable{
    @Id
    private int rollNo; 

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="birth_date")
    private Date birthdate;

    public StudentInfo(){};

    public StudentInfo(int rollNo, String name) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getRollNo() {
        return rollNo;
    }

    public void setRollNo(int rollNo) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getBirthdate() {
        return birthdate;
    }

    public void setBirthdate(Date birthdate) {
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }

}
```

However it gives me an error:

> Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Column 'birth_date' cannot be null

Why is that so? Thank you very much!

Comment: You are not givng the birthdate column a value. The database has a restriction on that days value has to be nont null. The error is very clear.

Comment: student.setBirthdate(new Date());

is this line not giving a birthdate value?

Comment: I try to insert one object only, and it works. I wonder why it doesn't work when I started using two objects.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and debug the code. The error is pointing to the fact that the birth date is not set. It is crucial to develop tje ability to debug code. For some reason the date is not set.

Comment: Trust me use a breakpoint and step through the code. You will learn a lot more by doing this than just following a tutorial. Debugging is essential for any developer.

Comment: When you find the answer post it here. I can certainly upvote effort. I could possibly give you the answer but I suspect u will learn more by debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You instantiate `student2` but then just set all the properties on `student` again, which means `student2`'s properties never get set and fail the database constraint. Set `student2`'s properties and you'll be fine.

```
    StudentInfo student = new StudentInfo();
    student.setRollNo(1);
    student.setName("Jo");
    student.setBirthdate(new Date());

    StudentInfo student2 = new StudentInfo();
    student.setRollNo(2);  # this isn't student2
    student.setName("JC"); # this isn't student2
    student.setBirthdate(new Date()); # this isn't student2
```

Comment: This is why I said debug it.